# how do I find where a executable is present in macosx?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a command called youtube-dl .. but dont know where it is installed.. i can run it from shell.. how do i find where it is installed ?  which youtube-dl  doesnt say anything..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you can't find it with `which` (or `whereis`) then it could be:

- a function defined in .bashrc or .profile (or some other file the shell loads on startup or login)
- an alias defined in one of the above files.

You can search your environment for youtube-dl:

```
$ set | grep youtube-dl
```

or save it to some file and load it into a texteditor:

```
$ set >myenv
$ open -a textedit myenv
```

and for the aliases:

```
$ alias >myalias
```

or

```
$ alias | grep youtube-dl
```

Comment: But you won't find aliases with it. In this case try e.g. `less .bash_profile | grep youtube-dl`.

Comment: Hey Luther, you are right. It was an alias and I was never able to find it in which and whereis.

Answer (score 36):

Bash has a command that will show whether a command is an alias, a function or an executable in your path (and, if so, where):

```
type -a youtube-dl
```

It's much better than `which` which doesn't include aliases or functions.

Comment: @mkrieger1: `type` includes functions and aliases while `which` doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried

```
whereis youtube-dl
```

?

Otherwise you could just search for it:

```
find / -name youtube-dl
```